# Solution concept in Benabou/Tirole (2006)

Tags: game-theory, bayesian-game

In a well known paper, [Benabou/Tirole](https://www.princeton.edu/%7Erbenabou/papers/AER%202006.pdf) (2006) examine `pro-social' behaviour in an environment in which others draw inferences about one's motives given the map from motives to behaviour in the population. This is very much an equilibrium analysis: if generous people donate to charity but selfish people don't, then people believe that you are selfish if you don't give (in the equilibrium), with implications for your utility level.

Although Benabou/Tirole talk about `equilibrium' in the paper, I'm a bit confused about exactly what they mean by this. Are they referring to a Bayes-Nash equilibrium? Or, since we want to talk about beliefs, are they thinking of a Perfect Bayesian equilibrium? Or something else?

Relatedly, I would be very grateful if anyone is aware of a more formal presentation of their model that outlines the strategy sets of each player, beliefs, etc.

Addendum: given that this is essentially a signalling game, I guess that the implicit equilibrium concept must be PBE?